# vbscript onload legacy code

Tags: html, vbscript

I know this question has been answered a million times over, over 2 decades or so however, I have legacy code (by that I mean old code that has been around for decades written in classic asp) and it uses a vbscript onload function and it works fine. However when I try to replicate (cut down version) myself it does not work can somebody direct me to the official answer. My code is in the same folder as the legacy code. I have also modified the legacy code and it still works so it cannot be caching.

I tried and all give me an error:

```
startup
startup;
startup()
startup();
vbscript:startup()
vbscript:startup();
```

I tried also, but no error but no result
    vbscript::startup()
    vbscript::startup();

My code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
<script language="vbscript">
  Sub startup()
    f1.browser.disabled = True
  End Sub
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="vbscript::startup()">

<form name="f1">
    <input list="browsers" name="browser">
    <datalist id="browsers">
        <option value="Internet Explorer">
        <option value="Firefox">
        <option value="Chrome">
        <option value="Opera">
        <option value="Safari">
    </datalist>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<p><b>Note:</b> The datalist tag is not supported in Safari or IE9 (and earlier).</p>

</body>
</html>
```

If I change it to JavaScript it does work as everyone else seems to suggest however WHY DOES MY LEGACY CODE WORK!!!

Without submitting the hole page can someone suggest something.

Comment: what web browser you are using? you should use IE8, 9 or 10

Comment: I'm confused: what's the "legacy code" that is working, and what language are you trying to rewrite it into?

Comment: Where you tried to execute the VBScript? You can't just have it anywhere, since it will work only after the element is loaded, hence the usage of onload. You have to be more clear.

Comment: @Martha question author means that the text box is disabled via the VBScript code.

Comment: I am not trying to rewrite I just updating the page with more functionality. I cloned the original page for testing purposes and made my modifications and during testing I kept getting errors in the F12 console window, I ended up converting only my onload function to javaScript and it worked fine.

Comment: I am using IE11 by the way and my original code works fine with the onload function written in VBScript so it is not a question of where it is a question of what did I add that is causing it. Is the fact I added a DataList causing it!!??

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have solved very similar problem and found on this reliable web site:

[Specifying legacy document modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/jj676915%28v%3Dvs.85%29)

following solution: using **x-ua-compatible** header.

```
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Use Internet Explorer 9 Standards mode -->
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9">
  <title>My webpage</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Content goes here.</p>
</body>
</html>
```